# Setup React-Storybooks with React-Apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollostack, react-apollo

Is there any way to use React-Apollo with React-Storybooks? Previously I was trying out Relay and there is a module (https://github.com/orta/react-storybooks-relay-container) that allowed for creating stub containers that wouldn't require network access but used static data.

Is there an equivalent for the React-Apollo framework? http://dev.apollodata.com/react/

FWIW I'm working with React-Native but the idea and setup behind everything should be very similar (For example I'm using https://github.com/storybooks/react-native-storybook instead of the web based solution)

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is a quite old question but I will post an answer here for any further dev partner that needs the answer. **please if this is good for someone and it is not clear enough just let me know and I will update my answer**

In order to make it work (`react-apollo` and `react-storybook`) you have few approaches from which my favorite will be to use [`MockedProvider`](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/e241140855a6e7977ee8953645cea70948545710/src/test-utils.tsx) from `react-apollo` what you basically want to do is to tell your UI that whenever an expected request is fired it should response with an expected response, so let's make an example using a component `<Avatar>` that needs the user data to render properly:

**Avatar.js**

```
class Avatar {
   // ...
   render() {
       // pretty avatar layout
   }
}

export const COLLABORATOR_QUERY = gql`
  query GetCollaborator($id: ID!) {
    Collaborator(id: $id) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      avatarImgUrl
    }
  }
`;

const AvatarWithData = graphql(
  COLLABORATOR_QUERY, {
    options: {
      variables: {
        // let's suppose that we got a static variable here to simplify the example
        id: '1'
      }
    }
  }
)(Avatar);

export default AvatarWithData;
```

**.stories/index.js**

```
import { addTypenameToDocument } from 'apollo-client/queries/queryTransform';
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/lib/test-utils';
import { COLLABORATOR_QUERY } from '../js/components/Avatar';
import Avatar from '../js/components/Avatar';

const mockedData = {
  Collaborator: {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Char',
    lastName: 'Mander',
    avatarImgUrl: 'https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/charmander.jpg',
    __typename: 'Collaborator'
  }
};

const query = addTypenameToDocument(USER_QUERY);
const variables = { id: '1' };
let mocks = [{ request: { query, variables }, result: { data: mockedData } }];

storiesOf('Mocked', module)
  .addDecorator((story) => (
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
         {story()}
      </MockedProvider>
  )).add('Avatar', () => {
      return (<Avatar />);
  });
```

I got some issues with this `addTypenameToDocument` import cause they use typescript and with my boilerplate create-react-app there is something wrong, but what I have done is to include the logic in that file within my project (very dirty, sorry for that).

**UPDATE: to avoid issue importing `addTypenameToDocument`** what I have done as I am using `create-react-project` is to run `eject` command and add the following to the `package.json` jest configuration:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(apollo-client)/).+\\.(js|jsx)$"]
```

The issue s that the guys at `apollo-client` has es6 within their builded files and you will get syntax error, on top of that if you are using react storybook you may wanted to add [this](https://gist.github.com/duranmla/70e1fbc97e10c3978cef9d8e340ef977) configuration to the webpack config of storybook.

**BEFORE DOING ALL OF THAT** I have found this: https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/seamless-integration-for-graphql-and-react-6ffc0ad3fead#.1um2z7abl on the Test section there is an excellent approach too (almost the same) but they do not use the `addTypenameToDocument` I haven't try myself yet but if it works you will be able to test without run the eject command of react-create-project

Other than that, you should be sure that your query and variables match exact the same that the request made by your UI component otherwise you will receive an error that not mocked found, and then you are ready to roll.

Comment: Thanks! Always answer old questions because we had just put this task in our backlog. But now we can re-prioritize and try out your solution. I'll comment back once we've tried it out and accept the answer if it works then.

Comment: Nice @JohnShelley thanks for your feedback I have also update with some recent findings! cheers!

Comment: @AlexisDuran hi, could you check this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026341/react-app-rewired-transformignorepatterns-on-apollo-client-3 I'm facing a similar problem, but I can't find the solution

Comment: Hey @pmiranda I would love to help you but after these years I am currently working with a very different set of technology that I would be hard for me to get back to this context and understand your situation. <3 Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your time Alexis, I finally could manage my problem, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

My case was similar, with another library, not React Storybooks, but with Apollo Client.

In case anyone are searching for the same, I post here what I did.

In jest config I had to put:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules\\/(?!(apollo-client)\\/).*/"
]
```

Of course, with installing `npm i -D identity-obj-proxy`