# react-app-rewired, transformIgnorePatterns on Apollo Client 3

Tags: jestjs, apollo-client, react-app-rewired

I have a React app with:

- react-app-rewired
- Apollo Client 3.5.5

I have an error when I try to use this import:

```
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
```

If I do `console.log(MockedProvider)` I got: `undefined`.

If in my jest config I add this:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/.*"]
```

It works and I got the proper console.log: `[Function: MockedProvider] { defaultProps: { addTypename: true } }`

That's fine, yes, but I'm getting errors in other partes of the app, like:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  4 | import Loader from 'react-loaders';
  5 |
> 6 | import 'loaders.css/loaders.css';
```

So, what could I do?

I don't get how to apply that only for Apollo Client.